# explanation about intent.getStringExtra and intent.putExtra in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent

I kinda new about using android studio and my teacher asked me to learn about how to use intent.getStringExtra and intent.putExtra.

please help to explain me about those two things.
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, intents are used to move between some android component like (activity, service, broadcast receivers ...etc) some time you need to pass some value between these components so you need to use put extra in the sender component and get extra in the receiver for example :

in the sender :

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(SenderActrivtiy.this, REciverActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("emailKey", "mm@email.com");
                startActivity(intent);
```

in the reciver:

```
String email =getIntent().getStringExtra("emailKey");
```

note that you need to pass the same key to retrieve your value